How to optimize non-contiguous memory copy with rotation in embedded Linux DRM driver
Background
I'm working on an embedded Linux project using LVGL with a DRM driver. I need to rotate the display content by 90 degrees because my physical screen is 1080x1920 (portrait) but the content should be displayed in landscape mode.
The DRM driver doesn't support hardware rotation, so I'm implementing the rotation in software during the frame buffer flush operation. The main challenge is that this creates a non-contiguous memory copy pattern, which significantly impacts performance (increase CPU resource consumption and reduce fps).
Current Implementation
Here's the simplified version of my flush function:
void drm_flush(lv_disp_drv_t *disp_drv, const lv_area_t *area, lv_color_t *color_p)
{
    struct drm_buffer *fbuf = drm_dev.cur_bufs[1];
    lv_coord_t w = (area->x2 - area->x1 + 1);
    lv_coord_t h = (area->y2 - area->y1 + 1);

    // For each pixel in the source buffer
    for (int y = area->y1; y <= area->y2; y++) {
        for (int x = area->x1; x <= area->x2; x++) {
            // Rotate coordinates 90 degrees
            int new_x = drm_dev.width - y - 1;
            int new_y = x;

            // Copy pixel to rotated position
            uint8_t *dst = (uint8_t *)fbuf->map + 
                          (new_x * (LV_COLOR_SIZE/8)) +
                          (fbuf->pitch * new_y);
            lv_color_t *src = &color_p[(y - area->y1) * w + (x - area->x1)];
            memcpy(dst, src, LV_COLOR_SIZE/8);
        }
    }
}

What I've Tried

OpenMP parallelization;
Row buffering to reduce memory fragmentation;
SIMD instructions (NEON on ARM);
Partial updates to minimize the area being copied;

However, the performance is still not satisfactory. The current implementation has O(n) complexity, and even with parallelization, the non-contiguous memory access pattern seems to be the main bottleneck.
Question

Is there a more efficient way to handle this kind of rotated memory copy operation?
Since the rotation angle is fixed (90 degrees), are there any mathematical optimizations we could apply?
Could we optimize the memory access pattern to better utilize the cache?
Are there any known algorithms or data structures that could help reduce the complexity below O(n)?

System Details

Platform: Embedded Linux (RV1126)
Display: 1080x1920 physical resolution
Color depth: 32-bit ARGB8888

Additional
Although I could solve this problem by remaking the UI in 1080x1920 resolution, I think it is unreasonable because it requires me to tilt my neck to design the program.
Any answers or comments are greatly appreciated.Thank you!

your question should be specific. you have much points. please narrow it down. btw, how do you expect memcpy to fall below o(n)?

You certainly can't get it below O(n).  Every one of the n bytes must be read, and then written somewhere else.  Asymptotic complexity is an important concept, but not the one that's relevant here.

@Chroluma, when you call for optimization (speed implied), consider posting a test harness to assess alternates' ratings versus your posted simplified one.  Otherwise, we are left with the ambiguous goal "the performance is still not satisfactory".  More science, less art.

Does not hardware support rotation?
